# jQuery plugin conflicting with other basic show/hide functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I bought (didn't code myself due to lack of education blah, blah, blah) a jQuery image slider/navigation plug in.  it works fine, and I have adjusted the images and CSS fittingly.

Problem is that when the slider is working properly, I cannot use a show/hide onClick event such as `$('#someId').toggle();`.

Using trial and error I have found that commenting a few lines of js on the html page allows the show/hide functions to work, but then the slider is broken,.

The js that I comment out comes after the slider images(plug-in).

The JS code in questin is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
            $jx('.slidedeck').slidedeck();
        </script>
```

When comment it out with html, then I can use `onclick="$('#someId').toggle();"` without a problem. But again, then the slider plugin is very broken and splattered all over the page.

As it is noticeable, and stated, I know nearly nothing.

Can anyone help me understand when this is happening?

Thanks

/Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
        $jx('.slidedeck').slidedeck();
</script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.slidedeck').slidedeck();
</script>
```

Comment: This worked! I presume that the "jx" is something in and of itself. Especially based upon Sirber's comment and the fact that it is missing. I will have to do some research to find out what "jx" is.

Comment: not really...

you PREVENT jquery from registering "$" when you use noConflict...

Comment: This works if you aren't using any conflicting libraries on the page. Plugin developers have no way of knowing what other libraries will be loaded on the page that their plugin is used, so they usually use the noConflict option. If you know the conflict will not be an issue, then this solution works.

Comment: no best way is: (function($){})(jQuery)... create it implicit-scoped..
but, it was clear, that he used only jquery ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

you have to use `$jx` or `jQuery`

ex: `onclick="jQuery('#someId').toggle();"`

Comment: `TheHe`'s answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is an alias for the jQuery method. Because there are other JavaScript libraries that may use the dollar sign as well, jQuery offers the noConflict method which basically renames the jQuery method to the variable that you set it to. (This way, it won't conflict with those other libraries.)

So, after the noConflict is called, all of your jQuery calls will need to replace the dollar sign with that variable. So in your example, just do this:

```
onclick="$jx('#someid').toggle();"
```